# Div content responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

i have a div, showing an image from the left of the screen when you click on it, as in the example in the following page
http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Although everything works fine on any computer screen, it doesnt happen the same with mobile devices. 
what should i do in order to make it responsive also to mobile devices?

```
 <div class="slide-out-div">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>some text</p>           
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-out-div {
      padding-bottom: 10%;
      max-width: 419px;
      max-height: 414px;
      background-image: url('../images/envl2.png');
      border: 0px ;
      z-index: 99;
}  


.slide-out-div p {
      font-family: 'Century Gothic';
      font-size: large;
      color: black;
      position: relative;   
      top: 45px; /*[wherever you want it]*/
      left:100px; /*[wherever you want it]*/
      width: 250px; /* change to your preferences */
      overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(340deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(340deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(340deg);
      writing-mode: lr-tb;     
}


.slide-out-div h3 {
         font-family: 'Century Gothic';
         font-size: 36px;
         color: black;
         text-align: left;
         text-decoration: bold; 
         position: relative;   
         top: 160px; /*[wherever you want it]*/
         left:50px; /*[wherever you want it]*/
         -webkit-transform: rotate(340deg);
         -moz-transform: rotate(340deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(340deg);
          writing-mode: lr-tb;
         }
```

i have tried to make it on jsfiddle but it is not working that good
http://jsfiddle.net/dnafdspa/

Comment: i have no experience on it but i guess you have use media queries in order to make it mobile friendly.

Comment: Media queries can be your best friend for applying styles differently based upon screen sizes but, as referenced in the answer below, your page is NOT responsive??

Answer (score 0):

It pops out just fine on my phone (iPhone 6), though it doesn't look like you did much to make your site responsive. A Google search for "responsive css tutorial" will be your best friend here.

I took a look at the first result and it seems to cover all the bases pretty well: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/